gnuplot: automatic counting of lines when plotting indexed data with transparency
I have some data files with the following structure. The first three columns are 3D coordinates (x, y, z) of points and the fourth column is an intensity value. The rows of values per group (i.e. points per group) can vary. So I need a function that automatically counts the number of points when plotting so that I can get a legend title like "group_0001: 10 pts.". I also want the intensity of the points to be plotted with transparency instead of size.
reset session

$Data  <<EOD
# group_0001
125.714 109.647 38.0402 0.79257
128.834 111.153 40.7486 0.753538
132.036 112.698 43.4124 0.793434
135.52  114.449 46.0812 0.776121
138.786 116.233 48.1499 0.793355
142.357 117.967 50.2387 0.731456
145.967 119.98  52.2324 0.787673
148.363 121.234 53.44 0.749578
149.448 121.81  54.0276 0.80474
153.108 123.831 55.9821 0.786737


# group_0002
111.44  146.587 81.1063 0.755904
112.27  151.103 82.1631 0.649881
112.995 155.321 83.3001 0.791218
113.763 159.66  84.2395 0.746114
114.551 163.53  85.1278 0.744113
115.437 168.114 86.1995 0.767338
116.344 172.465 87.481 0.742969


EOD


splot for [i=0:*] $Data index i pt 7 ps var


What is the intensity range? 0=opaque and 1=fully transparent or the other way round?

@theozh: just the other way round (1=opaque).

Here is a suggestion which

gets the block headers and the dataline counts per block into the legend
adds transparency to the datapoints depending on a column

In order to extract the block headers, you do set datafile commentschar '' together with columnheader(2). If your actual data looks different this needs to be adapted.
Transparency is calculated in a certain range (here: 0.6 to 0.9) and added via bitshift (<<24) to a color from a list.
I haven't succeeded in squeezing everything (i.e. variable color and title) into one plot command. Hence, there is a second plot command which is actually plotting nothing (NaN) but just providing the desired title. Maybe there is a shorter way which I haven't found so far.
This works only with gnuplot>=5.4.0 since the evaluation of variables in the title has been changed from then on.
Script: (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0)
### variable transparency and legend with count of datalines in each block
reset session

$Data  <<EOD
# group_0001
125.714 109.647 38.0402 0.79257
128.834 111.153 40.7486 0.753538
132.036 112.698 43.4124 0.793434
135.52  114.449 46.0812 0.776121
138.786 116.233 48.1499 0.793355
142.357 117.967 50.2387 0.731456
145.967 119.98  52.2324 0.787673
148.363 121.234 53.44 0.749578
149.448 121.81  54.0276 0.80474
153.108 123.831 55.9821 0.786737


# group_0002
111.44  146.587 81.1063 0.755904
112.27  151.103 82.1631 0.649881
112.995 155.321 83.3001 0.791218
113.763 159.66  84.2395 0.746114
114.551 163.53  85.1278 0.744113
115.437 168.114 86.1995 0.767338
116.344 172.465 87.481 0.742969
EOD

stats $Data u (B=column(-2)+1) nooutput  # get number of blocks
set datafile commentschar ''
set key noautotitle noenhanced
set ztics 10
set grid x,y,z vertical
set xyplane relative 0

myColors       = "0xff0000 0x00cc00 0x0000ff"  # your color list
cMin           = 0.60
cMax           = 0.90
myColor(col,i) = ((int(0xff*(1-(column(col)-cMin)/(cMax-cMin))))<<24) + int(word(myColors,i+1))

splot for [b=0:B-1] $Data index b u 1:2:3:(myColor(4,b)) w p pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb var, \
      for [b=0:B-1]    '' index b u 1:2:(c=$0,NaN) w p pt 7 ps 2 \
          lc rgb int(word(myColors,b+1)) ti sprintf("%s: % 3g pts.",columnheader(2), c) 
### end of script

Result:


I add hypertext labels to the points with a second 'plot' call and display the values of the points when I move the mouse pointer over the points. For me, there is no need for optimization. This is a very precise solution to my problem.

@magfan glad to hear :-)

Can I print the clusters sorted? I need the largest cluster first. The order of clusters of the same size does not matter.

@magfan with "printed" you mean the order in the legend by the group with the most datapoints first? How many groups do you typically have?

Yes, the order in the legend. There are typically between three and 20 groups.

@magfan well, unfortunately, gnuplot has no really good internal features for sorting lists, datablocks or arrays. Either you need external tools or a bit cumbersome workarounds. There are a few questions and answers here on SO. I will think about a way for your case.

@magfan assuming you have a certain color scheme (e.g. red, green, blue, ...) , do you want the colors to be fixed to the cluster (i.e. group1=red, group2=green, ...) or to the position (position1=red, position2=green, ...)?

There are three possibilities. First: groups are sorted by size and the colors are assigned to them according to the order in the color table. Second: make a size-to-color mapping so that groups of the same size have the same color. In both cases, there should be 18 different colors to clearly distinguish all groups, where group sizes 1 and 2 do not exist. Third: one color for all groups, but the intensity should be scaled between the minimum and maximum value of column 4. However, in order not to make it unnecessarily complicated, the first idea would already be very helpful.

You can count the number of data points plotted, and reset it for the different groups, using this trick.
cur_i=0
n=0
init(i)=(cur_i=i,n=1)
count(i,col)=((i!=cur_i)?init(i):n=n+1,column(col))

splot for [i=0:*] $Data u 1:2:3:(count(i,4)) index i pt 7 ps var  tit "group ".n." points"

